# How to mount an internal HDD on start-up?

Tags: filesystem, automount, hard-drive

I have a 500GB internal HDD where I store all my music and photos but it is annoying to manually mount it after a restart and I was wondering how to mount it automatically and make it available to Rhythimbox for playback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using [PySDM](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/) if you aren't looking to manually edit configuration files.

> PySDM is a Storage Device Manager that
>   allows full customization of hard disk
>   mountpoints without manually access to
>   fstab. It also allows the creation of
>   udev rules for dynamic configuration
>   of storage devices.
>   [image]

In Ubuntu, it can be installed by searching the Ubuntu Software Center for "pysdm". Once installed, it is available under the System --> Administration --> Storage Device Manager.

Comment: Zoot, could you please update your answer? Looks like PySDM is not available for installation through apt-get, because the project was discontinued. So you can only install it on precise and older versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: In that case, check out gnome-disks.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks
My understanding of that program is that Disk Drives->More Actions->Automatic Mount Options might also be able to help out.  I'll check it outwhen I am able to do so.

Comment: It's in the repos for <= 12.04 precise: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pysdm/

Answer (score 7):

You can add an entry in fstab to auto mount your partitions at Ubuntu startup. you can read more about fstab at [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)