# Newly created ubuntu users cannot access my internal hdd partitions

Tags: ext4

I have a problem with my ubuntu 11.10, the issue is described in the following link: [Hard disk icon disappears after mounting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89553/hard-disk-icon-disappears-after-mounting/)

After digging and digging I found the issue. It's a problem with ext4 partition, because I'm able to mount my NTFS partitions without any issue.

Here are the details.

### /var/log/syslog

> Dec 29 22:06:32 ms-Lenovo-G550 ntfs-3g[3240]: Version 2011.4.12AR.4
>   external FUSE 28
>
> Dec 29 22:06:32 ms-Lenovo-G550 ntfs-3g[3240]: Mounted /dev/sda2
>   (Read-Write, label "TEST", NTFS 3.1)
>
> Dec 29 22:06:32 ms-Lenovo-G550 ntfs-3g[3240]: Cmdline options:
>   rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1002,gid=1002,dmask=0077,fmask=0177
>
> Dec 29 22:06:32 ms-Lenovo-G550 ntfs-3g[3240]: Mount options:
>   rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,fsname=/dev/sda2,blkdev,blksize=4096,default_permissions
>
> Dec 29 22:06:32 ms-Lenovo-G550 ntfs-3g[3240]: Global ownership and
>   permissions enforced, configuration type 7
>
> Dec 29 22:06:38 ms-Lenovo-G550 kernel: [   45.141025] userif-2: sent
>   link up event.
>
> Dec 29 22:06:38 ms-Lenovo-G550 kernel: [  401.741884] EXT4-fs (sda8):
>   mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>
> ### root@ms-Lenovo-G550:~# mount |tail -2
>
> /dev/sda2 on /media/TEST type fuseblk
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
>
> /dev/sda8 on /media/Misc_ type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
>
> root@ms-Lenovo-G550:~# ls -la /media/
>   --- total 16
>
> drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 2011-12-29 22:15 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 2011-12-11 22:30 ..
>
> drwx------ 17 ms   ms   4096 2011-12-22 21:59 Misc
>
> drwx------  1 abc  abc  4096 2011-12-29 20:31 TEST

My question is how to mount ext4 as same as NTFS ?

Comment: After digging and digging I found the answer. It is due to "take ownership of filesystem" option in palimset(Disk utility). If you set that option while formatting any of the partition(ext4/ext3) you cannot write/read it under different user. Please close this question.

Answer (score 1):

OP posted the answer as a comment

> After digging and digging I found the answer. It is due to "take ownership of filesystem" option in palimset(Disk utility). If you set that option while formatting any of the partition(ext4/ext3) you cannot write/read it under different user.