# How can I connect to all drives automatically when I log in?

Tags: login, hard-drive, google-chrome, remmina

The download folder in my Google Chrome is a folder in another drive (partition). But when I log in, the folder cannot be opened through chrome unless I open the drive manually (with nautilus or dolphin).

There's a similar problem with remmina.

How can I connect to all drives automatically when I log in?

Comment: See if this helps you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19117/how-to-mount-an-internal-hdd-on-start-up

Answer (score 1):

Well , What type of ur partition? NTFS, FAT or Ext3?

You can mount your partition drive automatic so you when you start ubuntu you dont have to connect manually.This is the step. Open  disk utility.

[image]

Find out where the location of your drive you want to mount (Dont mount The system (ubuntu system partition) because it's already mount by ubuntu) .Like my drive is on /dev/sda2 and the type is NTFS

[image]

Open terminal and type:

sudo mkdir /mnt/windows [enter]  You can rename windows whatever you want.it's just example

sudo chmod 755 /mnt/windows [enter]

sudo gedit /etc/fstab    [enter]

and insert new line, like this

[image]

Save and restart ur pc. Now you can easy access ur files under /mnt/windows directory. 
You can doing this to all your drive but remember to using diferent name folder and diferent /dev/sda* . if your drive type is ext4/ext3 just change ntfs to ext4 on your /etc/fstab. Like this:

/dev/sda2 /mnt/windows ext4 defaults 0    0    [save and reboot].Good Luck

Comment: what does "defaults, unmask=007,gid=46  0          0" mean?

Comment: it's mean:

0 Owner read, write and execute
0 Group read, write and execute
7 Others No permissions
gid 46 is group user.